Cursor in contenteditable LI does not go to EOL on click (Chrome)
I am using a content editable list. Currently I am not able to solve the following chrome problem (it works fine in FF at least).
When you click after the end of the following lines, the cursor is placed after the line's last character, except for lines that have another UL inside. By accident I found out after disabling the list-style-type, it works as well.
What is causing this and are there any ideas on how to solve it? Is it a bug that I need to report to Chrome?


<ul contenteditable>
  <li>Works</li>
  <li>Doesn't
    <ul><li>Works</li></ul>
  </li>
  <li style="list-style-type: none">Works
    <ul><li>Works</li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>




I think this has nothing to do with JavaScript. Its html related though.

@user2804429 But maybe there's a JS solution to fix it.

To call it a bug you'd have to find something in the HTML specification that says how this is supposed to work. It may be unspecified and therefore left up to the implementation. But I agree that it seems inconsistent and non-intuitive.

Not yet an answer, but a refinement of your observation.
The behavior depends on whether you click really close to the end of the text (red arrow) or somewhere after it on the same imagined line (green arrow):




Click where
Chrome behavior
Firefox behavior




really close to "Doesn't"
Doesn't|
Doesn't|


somewhere after "Doesn't"
|Doesn't
Doesn't |


really close to unbulleted "Works"
Works|
Works|


somewhere after unbulleted "Works"
Works|
Works |



